# sqrt sign with sharp or rounded corner

Tags: formatting, math-operators

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
%MACRO
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt} % makes all sqrts closed
\renewcommand{\sqrt}[1][\ ]{%
\def\DHLindex{#1}\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
\setbox0=\hbox{$#1\oldsqrt[\DHLindex]{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0
\advance\dimen0-0.2\ht0
\setbox2=\hbox{\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
{\box0\lower0.71pt\box2}}
%MACRO
\begin{document}

$\sqrt{\frac{X}{Y}}$

\end{document}
```

is output

[image]

Is it possible rounded corner or sharp corner? How is it changing macro in MWE?

[image]

Related to: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to lower by `0.4pt` which is the width of the line

```
\box0\lower0.4pt\box2
```

With this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
%MACRO
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsqrt}{\sqrt} % makes all sqrts closed
\renewcommand{\sqrt}[1][\ ]{%
\def\DHLindex{#1}\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
\setbox0=\hbox{$#1\oldsqrt[\DHLindex]{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0
\advance\dimen0-0.2\ht0
\setbox2=\hbox{\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
{\box0\lower0.4pt\box2}}
%MACRO
\begin{document}

$\sqrt{\frac{X}{Y}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you need rounded corner then you can use `\pdfliteral` primitive, for example:

```
\let\sqrtori=\sqrt
\def\sqrt#1{\setbox0=\hbox{$\sqrtori{#1}$}\sqrtori{#1}%
            \raise\ht0\hbox{\kern-.2pt\sqrtZ\kern.5pt}}
\def\sqrtZ{\pdfliteral{q 1 j .3985 w 0 -.5977 m .5 -.5977 l .5 -2 l S Q}}

$\sqrt2$

\end
```

The result:

[image: sqrt2]

The constants used in the path construction are: 0.3985=0.4pt/bp and 0.5977=0.6pt/bp, because the rule thickness of sqrt symbol is given in pt and PDF primitive commands for drawing use bp.

My code is the example for plain TeX with pdfTeX. If you need to use LaTeX then you need to rewrite my example. I am not supporting LaTeX.